# Developing on a Dev Laptop

Tags: sharepoint

I am developing web applications for a SharePoint farm. On my laptop, I've attempted to setup my SharePoint site (I'm running Windows 7) as close as possible to the SharePoint site (Server 2008) on the farm. I had the administrator create a site template for me, but when I try to install it, I get errors saying that there are features on the farm that I do not have on my laptop (SSRS for one). Is there a way for the administrator to export the site from the farm so i can import without getting all the features not installed errors and without me installing all the features the server farm has?